# OperationalError: No such Column

Tags: python, django

I am very new to Python and working on the djbyexample tutorial.  I continue to get an operationalerror related to one of my two models and im not sure why (though i'm sure its an obvious answer).

I've set up two models:

```
from django.db import models

class DateTime(models.Model):
  datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.datetime)

class Item(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
  created= models.ForeignKey(DateTime)
  priority = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  difficulty = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  done = models.BooleanField(default=False)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

And my admin.py is as follows:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from models import Item, DateTime

class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ["name","priority","difficulty","created","done"]
  search_fields = ["name"]

class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model = Item

class DateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ["datetime"]
  inlines = [ItemInline]

admin.site.register(Item,ItemAdmin)
admin.site.register(DateTime,DateAdmin)
```

When attempting to access the Items model through the live admin I get the following Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/todo/item/

Django Version: 1.6.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'todo',
 'south')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/blake/.virtualenvs/Todo_List/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/blake/.virtualenvs/Todo_List/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  432.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/blake/.virtualenvs/Todo_List/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/blake/.virtualenvs/Todo_List/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/blake/.virtualenvs/Todo_List/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  198.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/blake/.virtualenvs/Todo_List/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/blake/.virtualenvs/Todo_List/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/blake/.virtualenvs/Todo_List/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/home/blake/.virtualenvs/Todo_List/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
  1411.             'selection_note': _('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt': len(cl.result_list)},
File "/home/blake/.virtualenvs/Todo_List/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  77.         self._fetch_all()
File "/home/blake/.virtualenvs/Todo_List/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  854.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/home/blake/.virtualenvs/Todo_List/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  220.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/home/blake/.virtualenvs/Todo_List/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  710.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/home/blake/.virtualenvs/Todo_List/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  781.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/blake/.virtualenvs/Todo_List/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  69.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/home/blake/.virtualenvs/Todo_List/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/blake/.virtualenvs/Todo_List/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  99.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/home/blake/.virtualenvs/Todo_List/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/blake/.virtualenvs/Todo_List/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  450.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/todo/item/
Exception Value: no such column: todo_item.created_id
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your database does not match your model. Either remove the table and resync, or use a migration tool to modify the table to match your model.

Comment: Do you know what caused this issue in the first place.  I have since deleted the db entirely and ran syncdb and is working but just trying to figure out where I erred in the first place. @Ignacio

Comment: You probably synced the database but then changed something (ForeignKey to DateTime); syncing again won't help in this case because the table already exists, so the column is missing.